# No me ordena los números bien

Tags: javascript, array, quicksort

Estoy haciendo una web de ordenar arrays con diferentes métodos de ordenamiento, con el método QuickSort si lo aplico en un console.log me lo da ordenado por ejemplo `3,2,1,10 = 1,2,3,10` pero al hacerlo con un formulario me lo ordena por el primer numero, por ejemplo `3,2,1,10 = 1,10,2,3`, Por que sucede esto?

https://jsfiddle.net/07adrLsu/

En esa web no funciona si lo ejecutas directamente, pero si en un archivo html y .js

Comment: Creo que el problema está en que los valores, si los tomas de elementos de HTML, te devuelven strings, por lo cual, deberías pasarlos a valores numéricos antes de compararlos, por ejemplo, con parseInt().
Si editas la pregunta y copias tu código podremos ver mejor el problema para ayudarte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como dice el comentario,  el problema es que estas ordenando los valores como strings.  Con `parseInt()` lo solucionas:

```js
function fixThat(){
 var metodo = document.getElementById("selectSort2").value;
 var userArray = document.getElementById("userArray").value;
 var fixArray = document.getElementById("fixArray");

 if (metodo == 1){
  var array = userArray.split(",");
  var array2 = quickSort(array);
  fixArray.setAttribute("value" , array2);
  console.log(array2);

 } else if(metodo == 2){
  alert("alv perese we");
 }
}


 //QuickSort//
function quickSort(array) {
 if (array.length < 1) {
  return[];
 }
 var izq = [];
 var der = [];
 var pivot = parseInt(array[0]);

 for ( var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (parseInt(array[i]) < pivot) {
   izq.push(array[i]);
  }
  else {
   der.push(array[i]);
  }
 }
 return [].concat(quickSort(izq), pivot, quickSort(der));
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>fuck it</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="insertArray">
   <input type="text" id="userArray" placeholder="Introducir array">
  </div>

  <div class="selectSorts">
   <select name="selectSort2" id="selectSort2">
    <option value="1" selected>QuickSort</option>
    <option value="2">ShellShort</option>
   </select>
  </div>
  <div class="fixButton">
   <input type="submit" id="fixButton" value="Ordenar" onclick="fixThat()">
  </div>

  <div>
   <input type="text" id="fixArray">
  </div>
 </div>
<script src="evanescence.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias de verdad, eso no lo sabía xD

Answer (score 0):

```js
function fixThat(){
 var metodo = document.getElementById("selectSort2").value;
 var userArray = document.getElementById("userArray").value;
 var fixArray = document.getElementById("fixArray");

 if (metodo == 1){
  var array = userArray.split(",");
  var array2 = quickSort(array);
  fixArray.setAttribute("value" , array2);
  console.log(array2);

 } else if(metodo == 2){
  alert("alv perese we");
 }
}


 //QuickSort//
function quickSort(array) {
 if (array.length < 1) {
  return[];
 }
 var izq = [];
 var der = [];
 var pivot = parseInt(array[0]);

 for ( var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (parseInt(array[i]) < pivot) {
   izq.push(array[i]);
  }
  else {
   der.push(array[i]);
  }
 }
 return [].concat(quickSort(izq), pivot, quickSort(der));
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>fuck it</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="insertArray">
   <input type="text" id="userArray" placeholder="Introducir array">
  </div>

  <div class="selectSorts">
   <select name="selectSort2" id="selectSort2">
    <option value="1" selected>QuickSort</option>
    <option value="2">ShellShort</option>
   </select>
  </div>
  <div class="fixButton">
   <input type="submit" id="fixButton" value="Ordenar" onclick="fixThat()">
  </div>

  <div>
   <input type="text" id="fixArray">
  </div>
 </div>
<script src="evanescence.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```